# Cannot change height of div.

Tags: asp.net, css, html, height, ssi

I cannot change the height of my div with CSS. It does not seem to be taking affect. Code below. I'm coding in C# ASP.NET with Javascipt and CSS. The below code is included in other files using SSI. The height of `.navdiv` will not alter no matter the value for `height:50px`.

ASPX

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="CSS/SSI/header.css" />
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <img id="imglogo" src="Images/logo.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <a class="navlink" href="default.aspx">
            <div class="navdiv" id="navhome">
                Home
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="navlink" href="import.aspx">
            <div class="navdiv" id="navimport">
                Import
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*
* header.css
* Created By: Steven T. Norris   Created On: 5/12/2012
* Update By:    Update On:
*
* Stylesheet for header SSI
*/

/*Main header style*/
#header
{

    background-color:#2875ff;
    border-color:Black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#logo
{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#navhome
{
    height:100px;
}

/*Navigation styles*/
.navdiv
{
    height:50px;
    background-color:#000999;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    font-size:large;
    text-align:center;
    color:#c24900;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navdiv:hover
{
    color:White;
}
#nav
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `display: inline-block;` will fix the height issue, but if you want the divs to still be side by side, be sure to add `float: left;` to both elements.

Answer (score 1):

The height property will not matter on elements with `display: inline`. It has to be `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: then the delima in my case becomes: How do I get divs to sit next to one another, be able to change the height via CSS, and only fill the width of their content??

Comment: Here's a good [article](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/) on `inline-block`

Comment: @ChaseFlorell using inline-block causes the divs to not be side by side and also to fill at 100% (using ie7)

Comment: In the [article](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/) that I linked there are some tips on how to make it work in old browsers.